# How to create a view or virtual folder for projects available in svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I don't how to frame the title for this question. If not appropriate please apologies.

Say for example. 
Previously, we had the svn structure something like below:

```
Product A
    Product A - Base
    Product A - Samples
    Product A - Tests
    Product A - Sub controls

Product B
    Product B - Base
    Product B - Samples
    Product B - Tests
    Prodcut B - Sub controls
```

So, if I want to get update on `Sub controls`, `Base`, `Samples` and `Tests` of `Product A`, Then, I'll go and get update directly for the parent folder `Product A` which I have in my local machine. A single update would be enough and very easy as well.

Currently, for some reasons we have changed the svn structure like below.

```
Base
    Product A - Base
    Product B - Base
Samples
    Product A - Samples
    Product B - Samples
```

Now, currently If I want to get svn update on projects of `Product A`. Then, I have to go to each folder and get update. This is time consuming when there more more projects associated with a project.

I would like to know, is there any way we can create a View [don't know the exact technical term in svn], so that, I can group `Prodcut A's` projects to a view or virtual folder from a single place I can get update for all the respective projects of `Product A`.

Note: The important thing is, the virtual folder or View should reside in my local machine and not in the svn. Since, I've got no permission to modify the structure or create one on my own.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get some of what you want using externals. However, this would require you to checkin actual folders into svn (so that they can host the externals), although this *could* be done in a different (private to you) repository. But then, using externally checkout folders isn't really fully transparent. Checking in stuff is clumsier.

I think the best way would be to figure out the best way to structure the repository and then change it to that structure, so that everyone benefits from this.

Comment: Wish there is a way. Thanks for the reply.